# Group Theory: Do groups support multiplying both sides of the same equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If I have two elements $a, b, x \in G$, with $G$ being a group, then if:

$a = b$,

does

$xa = xb$?

If so, what is the name of this property where you can multiply both sides of the equation by the same value?

Comment: It is simply the fact that the group operation is a well-defined binary operation.

Comment: That's going to be true for any structure where a binary operation is defined.  The trickier question, which also is true in groups but is not necessarily true in other structures with a binary operation, is whether $xa=xb \Rightarrow a=b$.

Comment: Generally speaking, if $a=b$, then you can replace $a$ by $b$ in any well-formed mathematical expression and get the same object.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of equality between $2$-tuples, $a=b\Longrightarrow (x,a)=(x,b)$. But group's operation is by assumption a *map* $m\colon G\times G\longrightarrow G$, *i.e.* to each element of the domain corresponds *one and only one* element of the codomain. Therefore, from $(x,a)=(x,b)$ necessarily follows $m(x,a)=m(x,b)$ or, in infix notation, $xa=xb$.